# items.map is not a function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm having a problem with fetching data from my api, and displaying it on a web page. I am getting this error : "items.map is not a function". Im not sure whether this is a problem with this code or maybe my code for my get request in the api, I'll post both codes just in case.

I'll paste my code below without the link to my api.
Thanks,

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
        items: [],
        isLoaded: false
    }

}

componentDidMount() {

  fetch(" api link ")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true, items: json });
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });

}


render() {

  const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

  if (!isLoaded)
      return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
      <div className="App">
          <ul>
              {items.map(item => (
                  <li key={item.oid}>
                      Name: {item.rows.productName} | Condition: {item.rows.productCondition}
                  </li>
              ))}
          </ul>
      </div>
  );

}

}

export default App;
```

Api code:

```
async function getComments(req) {
   let status = 500, data = null;
   try {

         const sql = 'SELECT * FROM products';
         const rows = await db.query(sql);

         if (rows) {
            status = 200;
            data = {
                rows,

            };
         } else {
            status = 204;
         }
     
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
   return { status, data };
}


app.get('/demo/api_project', async (req, res) => {
   const { status, data } = await getComments(req);
   res.status(status);
   if (data) res.json(data);
   else res.end();
})
```

Comment: what is the response from your api? post a sample response

Comment: your API response is an object, not an array. It looks like you should set the `items` state to `json.rows` rather than just `json`

Comment: @Vineesh as in what comes up when i open the api link?

Comment: Yes, If it is not an array you may have to use it or format it accordingly @JakubK

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks, oh dear i've been trying for so long. I thought it would of worked when i had the .rows in the item.productName etc

Comment: try ```items?.map```

Answer (score 1):

try console.log() your response from the api, you may find that is your array is nested inside the response object.

Comment: This could have been a comment